# I understand there's a rate limit for Twitter, but how many requests may you send?

Tags: twitter

I wanna make something that tweets something for my users every day at noon. So basically; When is it considered DDOSing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Twitter help center](http://support.twitter.com/entries/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following), the current api limits are 1000 updates per day,

> 1,000 per day. The daily update limit
>   is further broken down into smaller
>   limits for semi-hourly intervals.
>   Retweets are counted as updates.

For direct messages, this limit is 250 messages per day.

Comment: Yeah. And I know that posting a tweet will go through the clients rate limit (which is 350).. but how many requests (for unique clients) can I send at the same time?

Comment: Twitter's IP limits are posted here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting They're a little vague, you can decide if its an issue for you or not.  Supposedly HTTP POST commands are not limited but I know they will block really busy addresses such as hotels with large conferences being live-tweeted.